# How to initialize mysql database when user is installing software

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, installation

First of all, I realize that I might not be thinking about this problem correctly, but here goes.

So, I'm working on a Node project that will rely on a MySQL database. So, while I'm developing this app, I am merely pointing the connector to my already initialized database on my machine

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'Ethan',
   password: '***********',
   database: 'my_db'
});
```

However, when I think about this in the production phase, I'm wondering how I can initialize all of this when someone is installing my application. For instance, check if MySQL is installed, if not then install it. Once MySQL is there, how can I create `user`, `password`, and most importantly the `database`.

Is this possible to do this purely in node (with the `os` module perhaps). Or should I rely on a .sh file. Are there best practices for doing things like setting up a database on a user's computer (i.e. where to place everything).

Hopefully that question is clear enough, feel free to ask for clarification about anything.

Comment: check if MySQL is installed
what does it mean ? u need Mysql on your server not in user computer

Comment: @Adiii I plan on running a somewhat small database to store user information and aggregate other usage statistics. At least in my experience with mobile development, this is a fairly common practice.

Comment: yeah in mobile we do that like android but in that case, your apps direct communicate with OS with a complete set of permission but in your case, your web application will communicate with web browser not with os directly.

Comment: I think that I may not have been explicit enough, but this will be run as a desktop application through NodeWebkit.